# "object required" error message when updating labels in a form - Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to update 2 labels in a form when my code (vba) runs in an Access (2016) database.  I kick off the code and I get an "object required" error message when it hits the code below.  These labels appear on the "MAIN" form; which is opened when the database is opened.

I tried adding "MAIN." before each line.
I tried adding "Me." before each line.

I would also like to kick off the the sub "Get_Counts" that contains the code below when the form is opened.  The is a Private Sub Form_Load" that kicks off when the database is opened.  I would like to include in the "Form_Load" sub but haven't done anything like this before.

Nothing is working for me.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for the help....

```
Sub Get_Counts ()
....do stuff....
    ProgBar1.Caption = "Retrieving  Counts for: "
    ProgBar2.Caption = "Center 503"
....do more stuff....

End sub
```

Comment: Please format your code....

Comment: @TimWilliams....My bad.  I did it for the 2 ProgBar lines.  However, I went back and add the other code and forgot to do that again.......

Comment: So have you called Get_Counts() from form Load event? I use code that sets label captions in Load, Open, Current, Click events as well as report Format event and never had an issue.

Comment: Where is the `Get_Counts ()` method located? Behind the main form or in a standard module?

Comment: @KostasK.......It is located behind the main form.  The Get_Counts () code runs when the form is opened.

Comment: This is how I am trying to display the Prog Barlabels on the form:
    ProgBar1.Visible = True
    ProgBar2.Visible = True
    ProgBar3.Visible = True
    ProgBar3.Caption = "Please Wait"
    ProgBar1.Caption = "Retrieving Counts for: "
    ProgBar2.Caption = "Center 503"

Then I change the caption on ProgBar 2 each time a different sub-routine is called.

The subroutines are located in a different module.  Do they also need to be behind the main form?

Comment: @June7.........Can you show me how you set the label captions in the Load event.  My comment above shows the lines of code but they are aren't displaying.....I'm probably missing something but I'm not sure what it is.  Thanks for the help....

Comment: Only code behind a form can access the form's controls either with the `Me` keyword or without. Any other code either in a standard module or behind another form needs the fully qualified name e.g. `Forms.Main.ProgBar2.Caption`. The form of course must be loaded to access its controls.

Comment: @KostasK.....Thanks.  I made the module "private" behind the form and it still isn't displaying.  I just realized the labels are on the Detail sheet in the form.  Do I need to reference the Detail Sheet?  Thanks for your help...And the form is loaded.  This code kicks off on the Load event

Comment: Is the "Detail sheet" a form used as a subform? Either code goes behind that form or yes, must reference subform through the subform container that holds it. I always name containers different from the form they hold, like `ctrOrders`: `Me.ctrOrders.Form.Label1.Caption`.

Comment: @KostasK......Thanks for all of the help June7 and KostasK.  I used the Repaint command and it solved my issue.  Thanks for sharing your knowledge and experience......